# Check if TcpClient was not called -X IsNot Nothing vs Not X Is Nothing [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

How do I check if the function has defined TcpClient before?
I'm using a Sub to open a connection and a timer to check if the connection is still alive ( using the same Sub!).

```
Public clientTest as TcpClient = nothing

Sub OpenCheckConnection()
  If clientTest is not Nothing AndAlso clientTest.Connected = True Then
     pictureboxTest.Image = xxGreen
  Else
     clientTest = New TcpClient
     Try
       clientTest.Connect(IPtest, Porttest)
     Catch ex As Exception
       NewLog(ex.ToString)
     End Try
'
      If clientTest.Connected = True Then
      (...)                 '
      Else
         pictureboxTest.Image = xxRed
      End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I've tested this and `clientTest is not Nothing` is not defined for TcpClient. `"clientTest <> 0` is not defined as well.
How can i manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsNot`. One word:

```vb
If clientTest IsNot Nothing ...
```

Alternatively, you can write this:

```vb
If Not (clientTest Is Nothing) ...
```

`Nothing` for reference types is a special value, and negating it directly via a logical `Not` doesn't help you. A logical `Not` of an unknown value is still an unknown value.

Instead, you want either the `IsNot` logical inverse for the `Is` operator, or just the `Is` operator where you place the logical `Not` to negate the entire boolean expression.